# How to access class constructor parameters in a companion object

Tags: kotlin

I would like to access the arguments passed to the class constructor in a companion object :

```kotlin
class Home(private val activity: String) {
    companion object {
        fun doSomething() {
            println(activity)
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    Home("Hello World").doSomething()
```

However, an error is raised when I run this code saying that `activity` is unresolved reference

Comment: The companion object doesn't have access to the instance of Home object. You cannot call `Home("Hello World").doSomething()`, but can only call `Home.doSomething()`

Comment: The companion object is like a static method, it's not an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A companion object is basically the equivalent of a Java static nested class (and that's how it's implemented under the hood), which means an instance of the static nested class could exist even with no instance of the outer class.
Example:

```
class Outer(private val activity: String) {
    companion object {
        fun doSomething() {
            println("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    Outer.doSomething() // no new Outer instance here
}
```

If you want a non-static nested class (aka inner class) you can then reference properties of the outer class from within the inner class. That's because instances of the inner class are tied to instances of the outer class.
Example:

```
class Outer(private val activity: String) {
    inner class Inner {
        fun doSomething() {
            println(activity)
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    Outer("Hello, world!").Inner().doSomething()
}
```

For more info, you can also have a look at Java documentation about nested (aka static) and inner (aka non-static) classes here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html